# Python GUI apps without "Python.app"?

Tags: python, wxpython, tkinter

I've recently started using Tkinter, and now I'd like to try wxPython, but I have one major problem: on Mac, the Python app launches and runs the gui. I'm using Platypus, so window already has an app to "attach" itself to. Why does it need Python.app as well? Is there a way to get around this? This method feels as "thrown together" as running a Windows application inside Wine inside X11 on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. The whole point of Platypus is that it can turn non-GUI scripts into GUI apps. The "app" and "window" are invisible to the script, which thinks it's just receiving stuff via sys.argv and writing to stdout.

The [Platypus documentation](http://sveinbjorn.org/files/manpages/PlatypusDocumentation.html) explicitly says that Platypus is "not intended to be used to create substantial Mac OS X applications with complex user interaction".

The wxPython documentation says all over the place that you should be using py2app (e.g., http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X) to build wx apps on Mac. (You may find a bit of out-of-date docs that mention BundleBuilder instead, but ignore that.)

If you really know what you're doing, maybe you can ignore the documentation for two different packages and force them together to do what you want, but otherwise, why even try?

If you want to package up a GUI app that's aware of its GUI—whether it's TkInter, wx, or something else—the way to do that is with [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html). Without learning anything beyond the tutorial you can turn a wxPython (or PyQt or TkInter or whatever) script into a double-clickable Mac app. And you can customize it to almost any extent you want (export UTIs, assign icons to filetypes, …). And wxPython's documentation already tells you how to do it.

By the way, I suspect part of the problem here is that you don't know about the distinction between OS X apps, and Unix executables. But if you stick to cross-platform toolkits (like wx) and py2app, you can probably get away with that.